# SQL add extra column with a value

Tags: sql

I want to add an extra column with an optional name besides the counted column below, the code that i wrote it is as below and shows the result as below

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TBL_STUDENTS_INFO where 
TBL_STUDENTS_INFO.come_from_university is not null
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TBL_STUDENTS_GO
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TBL_STUDENTS_TAJIL

    Result
    COUNT(ID)
    41
    88
    9
```

i want the code to show the result like this

```
Extra_Column      Counted
cnt_come_uni      41
cnt_go            88
cnt_tajil         9
```

Comment: Programming questions like this are off topic here. You have a [SO] account; have you posted on the wrong site?

Answer (score 1):

i could solve the above query with below code

```
SELECT 'come' label, to_char(COUNT(ID)) FROM TBL_STUDENTS_INFO where TBL_STUDENTS_INFO.come_from_university is not null
UNION ALL
SELECT 'go' label, to_char(COUNT(ID)) FROM TBL_STUDENTS_GO
UNION ALL
SELECT 'taji' label, to_char(COUNT(ID)) FROM TBL_STUDENTS_TAJIL
```

now it is show as this, as i expected

```
LABEL        NO of students
come          41
go            88
taji          9
```